# Необходимо решение для нечёткого поиска в бд

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Подскажите пжл решение по поиску на сайте для такого кейса:

```
Hello world - так ищет
Helloworld - так не находит
```

Нужно решение, чтобы запись была найдена если даже юзер ввел слитно.

Comment: зависит от БД. в postgresql, например, есть подходящий поиск по триграммам, pg_trgm

Comment: В sql servere это near